# submit crash logs to Apple via iTunes Connect

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect, crash-log

How can I force an iPhone or iPod Touch to send/update its crash logs to Apple?

I can crash an app within my device. When I visit [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com), I don't see any crash logs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't force it. And the crash logs are not uploaded to Apple by the device. They are uploaded by iTunes when the user syncs the device.

You know that you can grab the crash logs directly from the device by using Xcode? Connect your device and open the Organizer window in Xcode. It will show all crash logs available on the device.

Comment: I synced my device to itunes, and i still don't get any crash log on itunesConnect.  think i need to enable this, but how?

Comment: No they are simply not all uploaded to iTunes connect. Or periodically. WHo knows. Use Xcode instead that will give you direct access.

Answer (score 0):

Crash logs are only synced from the device to your iTunes Connect account (via iTunes) if the device preferences allow crash reporting. I don't know how to change this preference directly, but you can set it the first time you sync your device after resetting the warning messages for the device. You can find a step-by-step here:

http://www.appsmini.com/iquakelite/howtosendcrash.html

If it's your users' crash logs you're really interested in -- not your own, which you can get directly off the device -- this explains why some users' crash logs are available in iTunes Connect and some aren't.