# Crash reports in redesigned iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store-connect, crash-reports

I have a few questions:

1. Where is the crash report tab now in the redesigned [itunesconnect.apple.com](http://itunesconnect.apple.com)? Previously it used to be below "Additional Information"?
2. Does the crash report (crash report in iTunes) contain a UDID? I am asking because I'm wondering how I can identify which UDID a particular crash happened for?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The menu doesn't seem to be available any more. (Besides that you mostly did not see any crashes in there anyway, so it wasn't useful)

   **Correction** As @yeahdixon notes the crash reports link is now available below `Additional Information`.
2. Crash reports never contain the device UDID and are always anonymous.

Answer (score 42):

The crashreports are now in XCode.

In XCode, open the "Organizer" Window.

In the Organizer, select an app, and click on the "Crashes" tab.

Comment: Indeed ! Thank you ! However, it s empty for me... Is there something else to do to see crash report ?

Comment: If it is empty, then there were no crashes, or if there were, the people experiencing the crashes did not opt-in to the data gathering.

Comment: Hum :/ Okok, well hope it s the first option ahah

Comment: @Mayeul For future reference of anyone else that might see this make sure the correct app store version is selected. Xcode allows you to narrow down viewable crash logs by version which could be confusing for some developers if they've updated their app.

Comment: Hi AnthonyOSX - i can see the crash report for my app but i cant understand the crash report. it is nothing found my app related code.what i do?

Answer (score 18):

in iTunes connect, you can go to versions and scroll to: Additional Information at the  bottom and click crash reports

[image]

Comment: would you care to attach a screenshot? I'm lost in itunesconnect menutils

Comment: That link just leads me to a FAQ about crash reports, nothing about getting them from Apple.

Comment: This is not seen now, any idea why ?

Comment: @NavyaRamesan this was removed and added to XCode

Answer (score 12):

@Kerni Looks like with new update the above described options are not available any more. Please follow the below steps to retrieve crash logs

- Add iTunes connect detail in account section of Xcode preferences.
- Then go to Window-> Organiser. You will get screen like https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-crashes_organizer/AboutCrashesOrganizer/AboutCrashesOrganizer.html where crashes are listed.

Answer (score 6):

If you open iTunes connect in a web browser, click on "App Analytics" and select the app you are interested in, then a graph of crash reports will be shown at the bottom right. The title of this graph "Crashes" is a hyperlink and will take you to a more detailed crash report graph. However, to see the actual call stack for any individual crash, you will need to do this from the XCode Organizer tool.

The Google Developer console provides much more detail for reported app crashes in the browser as well as making it much easier to view user reviews. So Apple certainly has room for improvement here.

Answer (score 1):

My app was released yesterday, but there is no option for viewing crash reports in iTunes Connect for me at this point.

[image]

Comment: yes you are right, i have googled and see many blogs at the time i posted question, i came to conclusion that our app users must send diagnostic reports to apple from setting option.Also apple will take time to publish it on itunes connect.SOME LINKS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241695/i-can-not-get-a-crash-report-in-itunes-connect    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208557/submit-crash-logs-to-apple-via-itunes-connect